# fill vector down based on previous values and change future values based on previous values

Tags: r

I have a vector of hotel stays. Each row represents a new day. The vector is filled with the following options:
1. 'first start' - represents start an individuals first stay at the hotel
2. 'NA' - represents time an individual is at the hotel (cannot be start or end of the stay)
3. 'end' - represents the end of an individuals stay (can be the end of any of their stays. yes, individuals can stay multiple times.
4. 'another start' - represents the start of a stay after the first stay. can be the second or third or fourth etc (some people will visit the same hotel 10+ times)
5. 'first start end' - represents a person that stays only one day for their first stay
6. 'another start end' - represents a person that stays only one day for a stay that is not their first

I also have a person id variable.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUxH3.png) is a sample of what I have and what I want

```
      Person_ID Have                Want
 [1,] "1"       "first start"       "1" 
 [2,] "1"       "NA"                "1" 
 [3,] "1"       "NA"                "1" 
 [4,] "1"       "end"               "1" 
 [5,] "1"       "another start"     "2" 
 [6,] "1"       "NA"                "2" 
 [7,] "1"       "NA"                "2" 
 [8,] "1"       "NA"                "2" 
 [9,] "1"       "end"               "2" 
[10,] "1"       "another start"     "3" 
[11,] "1"       "NA"                "3" 
[12,] "1"       "end"               "3" 
[13,] "1"       "another start"     "4" 
[14,] "1"       "NA"                "4" 
[15,] "1"       "end"               "4" 
[16,] "1"       "another start end" "5" 
[17,] "1"       "another start"     "6" 
[18,] "1"       "NA"                "6" 
[19,] "1"       "end"               "6" 
[20,] "1"       "another start end" "7" 
[21,] "1"       "another start end" "8" 
[22,] "2"       "first start"       "1" 
[23,] "2"       "NA"                "1" 
[24,] "2"       "end"               "1" 
[25,] "3"       "first start end"   "1" 
[26,] "3"       "another start"     "2" 
[27,] "3"       "NA"                "2" 
[28,] "3"       "end"               "2" 
[29,] "4"       "first start end"   "1" 
[30,] "4"       "another start end" "2" 
[31,] "4"       "another start"     "3" 
[32,] "4"       "NA"                "3" 
[33,] "4"       "end"               "3"
```

I tried using a loop, but my file is ~500,000 rows long and it took too long to run automatically, any suggestions for efficient ways to do this would be much appreciated! thanks!

Comment: Try `ave(Have,Person_ID,FUN=function(x) cumsum(grepl("start",x)))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tidyverse` package. Assuming you have a matrix named df containing your data:

```
library(tidyverse)

result <- df %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate_at("Have", funs(if_else(. %in% c("end", "NA"), NA_character_, .))) %>% 
  fill(Have) %>% 
  group_by(Person_ID) %>% 
  mutate(Want = as.factor(Have) %>% forcats::fct_inorder() %>% as.numeric())
```